# 90 degree right angle connectors

Tags: rf, connector

It is known that 90 degree bends causes signal loss and distortion. But does SMA 90 degree right angle connector still cause signal loss? If so, why are these connectors commercially used?

Comment: "It known that[...]" can you provide a citation? At what frequency range is this relevant? Does it overlap with the frequency range these connectors are rated for?

Comment: I meant its a general design rule specification of not to have 90 degree tracks.

Comment: I've never seen a satisfactory explanation of why that is, though. I'm not sure it's not just people repeating things they heard decades ago out of context; 90° bends certainly aren't a problem at DC.

Comment: For PCB tracks, 90 degree corners are not advised because sometimes fabrication might mis-form the inside corner, or perhaps form a crack there.  For EMI reasons, it's a very different situation, but it has to do with the geometry of the corner and if you care about rise times in the picosecond range (99% of designs don't care that deeply).

Comment: The issue with square corners is that the trace capacitance (on a PCB) at the corner is greater than the rest of the (straight) trace, because of the diagonal distance from the inside to the outside of the corner.  However, such affects can generally be ignored for typical 50 ohms traces and rise/fall times >10 ps.

Comment: @SteveSh That's about what I thought--outside of extremely high frequencies, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's not.

There is some loss (mainly in terms of reflection loss, not dissipation) due to full rectangular 90 degree bends in traces, which can be interpreted as the corner being a momentary widening of the trace and thus a low-Zo section, or having some capacitance.

There is also a dispersion effect, as surface or bulk waves can cross from one segment to the other (straight line distance), before the bulk of the guided wave (following the trace itself) arrives.  This is more specific to microstrip, and already a small effect; it's even smaller in stripline, and smaller still in coaxial (or other shielded) transmission lines.

Just because these are effects, doesn't mean they are relevant in any particular application.  In fact these are small effects (I would guess, <10% for wavelengths larger than the trace's electrical width), with magnitude asymptotically proportional to the electrical length of the feature.  That is, at lower and lower frequencies, the effect quickly becomes negligible, even for very precise applications.

Say you need 0.1% accurate Zo at 1MHz: then you need to avoid features on the order of 1GHz.  Which means, ballpark some ~cm of mismatch is still acceptable.  A corner of even 1mm width is therefore negligible in such an application.  It might not at 10GHz though.

These features are most important at high precision and wideband applications; you wouldn't want a wide corner geometry in a 20GHz oscilloscope, where you will indeed see some TDR effect for example.

The loading effect (low Z or capacitive) of the full corner is easily avoided by chamfering it, or using a few angled segments to approximate a curve (the corners of which might also be chamfered, to a smaller extent than for the 90° corner), or an arc proper.  The dispersion effects are small to begin with (fractional percent, I guess? -- coupling between adjacent microstrip is small to begin with (<20% at typical minimum trace space/width rules), and the distance increases rapidly with distance from the corner feature), and shielding (via fence or coax) eliminates the path entirely.

If you're using the SMA connectors at just a few GHz, you will likely not see any difference at all from such a construction.  It may also be that the dielectric or outside corner was relieved, keeping Zo more consistent around the bend.  If you're doing a 20GHz+ bandwidth TDR, you can likely see a small blip due to it; but you will also see blips due to the change in diameter and taper of the cable-connector joint, and perhaps mode breakup (at frequencies / edge rates where the SMA connector itself (or other structures in the path) ceases to be TEM00).

In short: the connector will perform as well as it is specified to do.  Whether that's in terms of Zo and flatness, frequency response, SWR, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

The bend radius is important. The SMA connectors likely don't have a straight 90 degree bend with zero radius, but a smooth curve.

That's very different to narrow PCB tracks with 90 angle edge without any adjustments. Even a 90 degree angle might be acceptable if mitered.

Comment: Having soldered some onto cables, I can confirm that they do not (at least not all) have a smooth curve. The inlet cable's center conductor is soldered into a slot in the connector's center pin, making a clear 90° angle.

Comment: See https://tools.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/733910230_sd.pdf for instance.

Comment: SMA connectors can have either right angle corners (formed when two pieces of wire are soldered inside the connector body) or curved/swept turns.